# How to repeate the value of the last day of February for a leap year in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, lubridate, leap-year

I have a `data.frame` that doesn't account for leap year (ie all years are 365 days). I would like to repeat the last day value in February during the leap year. The `DF` in my code below has fake data set, I **intentionally** remove the leap day value in `DF_NoLeapday`. I would like to add a leap day value in  `DF_NoLeapday` by repeating the value of the last day of February in a leap year (in our example it would Feb 28, 2004 value). I would rather like to have a general solution to apply this to many years data.

```
set.seed(55)
DF <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2003-01-01"), to= as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(1096, 0,10),
                 Z = runif(1096,5,15))
DF_NoLeapday <-  DF[!(format(DF$date,"%m") == "02" & format(DF$date, "%d") == "29"),  ,drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete` on the 'date' column which is already a `Date` class to expand the rows to fill in the missing dates

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- DF_NoLeapday  %>% 
           complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = '1 day'))
dim(out)
#[1] 1096    3

out %>% 
    filter(date  >= '2004-02-28', date <= '2004-03-01')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  date           A     Z
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2004-02-28  9.06  9.70
#2 2004-02-29 NA    NA   
#3 2004-03-01  5.30  7.35
```

By default, the other columns values are filled with `NA`, if we need to change it to a different value, it can be done within `complete` with `fill`

If we need the previous values, then use `fill`

```
out <- out %>%
          fill(A, Z)
out %>% 
         filter(date  >= '2004-02-28', date <= '2004-03-01')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  date           A     Z
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2004-02-28  9.06  9.70
#2 2004-02-29  9.06  9.70
#3 2004-03-01  5.30  7.35
```

Comment: Thanks- how I can repeat the values at 2004-02-28 for 2004-02-29?. I have many years data so I want to do this for all the leap years.

Comment: @Hydro You can just use `fill` at the end, it would repeat the previous non-NA values